# Paramiko channel.recv(1024) How to Flush out the channel messages older

Tags: python, python-3.x, paramiko

I have the below code but it prints all the logs but I only want the last command log from the paramiko channel.recv()

#Unnecessary this output also comming/printing

```
  channel.send("python "+pycmd+"\n")
  channel.send("rm "+sys.argv[10]+"/"+py_file+"\n")
```

#The output of this command I need

```
     channel.send("cat "+sys.argv[16]+"\n")
     op_t=(channel.recv(1024).decode('UTF-8', 'ignore'))
     op_t_output = op_t.lower().replace("\r\n", " ").strip()
     print(op_t_output)
```

How can I get the last cat command out put only

Comment: Hi Martin I need the file content output into the console via using cat command but it is not printing the file content...but it is printing the output of its previous commands

Comment: Well, your code  does not seem to try to read all output, it just reads the first at most 1024 bytes. And to read file contents, you better use SFTP anyway, not shell commands.